# What the purpose of the getSelectedItem() from the ListView

Tags: android, listview

What the purpose of the getSelectedItem() from the ListView if a list can't keep state of a selected item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can keep track of a selected item if you were to use say, a checkbox or a checkedtextview, but if you want to keep track of your selected items via a "highlighted background", then it's not possible (unless you want to have a hidden checkbox)

Comment: check out 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List11.html

or 

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List10.html

for examples

Answer (score 0):

`getSelectedItem()` is actually quite useless for `ListView`. `getSelectedItem` is defined in [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html), so there are other widgets that make better use of this method.

If you need to access the current item when it's selected, set the appropriate `OnItemClickListener` or `OnItemLongClickListener`.