# Pass Listview selection from one class to another and change button text

Tags: android

I have a class with a `ListView`. Once the user makes a selection I want to pass that selection to the button on the previous class. This is what I have so far:

```
public class SetupNewCourse extends Activity {
    String[] tees;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setup_new_course);

        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SetupNewCourse.this, selectTee.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // following code is the hang up I know its in the wrong place
                selectTee buttonText = new selectTee();
                buttonText.returnTeeSelection();
                b.setText((CharSequence) buttonText);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Following is my `ListView` class

```
public class selectTee extends ListActivity {

    String[] tees_list;
    String selectedText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tees_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tees_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view,
                tees_list));
        final ListView teelist = getListView();
        teelist.setChoiceMode(1);
        teelist.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        teelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> teeAdapter, View arg1, int selectedInt, long selectedLong) {
                selectedText = (String) (teelist.getItemAtPosition(selectedInt));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println(selectedText);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public String returnTeeSelection() {
        return selectedText;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult()` instead `startActivity()`.
There is explanation of using this method in [the documentation of the `Activity` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Comment: I now get an error at line data.setDate... I am sure it is because I do not have the proper syntax to get the result from list view. any ideas?                                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> teeAdapter, View arg1, int selectedInt, long selectedLong) {
    
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.setData(Uri.parse(teelist.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
   }
   
   
  });

Comment: I guess you get NPE. Try to use `teelist.getItemAtPosition(selectedInt).toString()` instead of `teelist.getSelectedItem().toString()`. `getSelectedItem()` returns selected item, not clicked. Click on item doesn't means selecting it. You can find explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6852764/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sergey said,

You should use `setResult(int result, Intent data);` in the `selectTee` activity and set the selected list items i.e. the data you want to propagate back with `data.putExtra("selectedText", selectedText)`